# How to check if a slice of a tuple in a set of tuples is in another set of tuples?

Tags: python-3.x, set, tuples

Assuming: I have two sets of tuples, also either set might not contain the same amount of tuples.
Is there any way I can get this to work without iterating over both sets and comparing every entry from one set to every entry of the other set?

For example, I´d like to know whether three entries of one tuple are in any of the tuples of the other set, this is what I´ve tried (example code):

```
s1 = set()
s2 = set()
s1.add(tuple(["a", "b", "c", "e"]))
s1.add(tuple(["d", "e", "f", "h"]))
s2.add(tuple(["a", "b", "c", "d"]))
s2.add(tuple(["d", "e", "f", "g"]))
s2.add(tuple(["m", "n", "o", "p"]))

for x in s1:
    if x[0:3] in s2:
        print(x)
```

This won´t work.

I´m asking because the sets have thousands of entries and iterating over both
takes way too long and I can´t seem to figure out a smart way to do it.

Edit for clarification:
Each tuple always has the same amount of entries, in my case 4.
In my case I´d like to know how to check any arbitrary combination [0:2], [1:3], [0:x]. I need confirmation that for example [0:3] in one tuple is the same as [0:3] in another one.

Comment: Your question needs more clarity. Why only x[0:3]? Based on your example, you should be checking for x[1:4] also. And if you do not know about the length of tuple then every 3 item subset from the tuple should be checked. Do you want to check presence of a particular tuple in set2 or just want a confirmation that there exists a tuple in s2 which contains a slice of 3 elements from s1?

Comment: Note that ``tuple(["a", "b", "c", "e"])`` can be written just as ``("a", "b", "c", "e")``. There is no need to use lists as initialiser.

Comment: "I´m asking because the sets have thousands of entries and iterating over both takes way too long and I can´t seem to figure out a smart way to do it." – a specialised data structure such as a [suffix tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Suffix_tree) might be needed. If the alphabet is small (4 entries and lower slices do not seem like regular words) just creating a single index might be possible. It is difficult to tell without knowing what exactly you actually want to achieve, though.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi i have two sets of tuples, each set has an arbitrary amount of tuples, each tuple regardless of which set always consists of 4 strings.

Comment: @JayRage Does each tuple consist of four *characters* or of four *strings*? Is the alphabetic the entire UTF-8, ASCII, alphanumeric, lower-case letters, or less? Is there overleap in the tuples of each set?

Answer (score 1):

You could use pandas for this. Pandas is optimised to run very fast using C bindings.

df1

```
0   1   2   3
0   a   b   c   e
1   d   e   f   h
2   x   e   f   h
3   y   u   d   h
```

df2

```
0   1   2   3   4   5
0   a   b   c   d   None    None
1   d   e   f   g   None    None
2   m   n   o   p   None    None
3   b   c   d   y   u   d
```

I've assumed above that the tuples may be of varying length.

```
import pandas as pd
df1 = pd.DataFrame([tuple("a", "b", "c", "e"), tuple("d", "e", "f", "h"), tuple("x", "e", "f", "h"), tuple("y", "u", "d", "h") ])
df2 = pd.DataFrame([tuple("a", "b", "c", "d"), tuple("d", "e", "f", "g"), tuple("m", "n", "o", "p"), tuple("b", "c", "d", "y", "u", "d")])


# checks if the first 3 column values are in the second frame
df1[[0,1,2]].isin(df2).any(axis=1)


0     True
1     True
2    False
3     True
dtype: bool
```

So it's matched abc, def, and yud in *any* location in the second dataframe. You could generalise this approach to look for subsets of the first dataframe other than cols 0:2. This could look something like this:

```
for col_max in range(0, len(df1.columns)):
    col_names = [col_index for col_index in range(0, col_max)]
    print(df1[col_names].isin(df2).any(axis=1))
```

Comment: Wow! Did not know this was possible like this! Nice library!

Comment: In my case I´ve tried:
df1 = pd.DataFrame(s1)
df2 = pd.DataFrame(s2)

print(df1[[0, 1, 2]].isin(df2).any(axis=1))

This however will result in varying results, sometimes none True, sometimes all False, sometimes the correct result. Could it be, that it depends on how the tuples in the sets are ordered?

Comment: Sets are unordered - "Unordered means when we display the elements of a set, it will come out in a random order.". When I load the set `{('a', 'b', 'c', 'd'), ('d', 'e', 'f', 'g'), ('m', 'n', 'o', 'p')}` into a dataframe, the tuple `('a', 'b', 'c', 'd')` ends up as the last row but you would expect it to be on the first row based on the order of the set when printed. You could just do ```list(set(tuples``` to maintain order.

Comment: @forgetso yes, that´s what I´ve read, but then your approach doesn´t work for me, I´m getting weird results (changing every time i run the program) using 
print(df1[[0, 1, 2]].isin(df2).any(axis=1))

Comment: After you have created the sets, convert them to lists, `list1` and `list2`. The order will be fixed. Take a look at the order. Then run the dataframe commands passing in the newly created lists, e.g. `df1 = pd.DataFrame(list1)` and `df2 = pd.DataFrame(list2)`. The output of `df1[[0, 1, 2]].isin(df2).any(axis=1)` will be directly associated with the order of `list1` and `list2`.

Comment: @forgetso the issue is, the order shouldn´t matter since I want to compare each tuple in the first to every tuple in the other set. From my opening Post: " Is there any way I can get this to work without iterating over both sets and comparing every entry from one set to every entry of the other set?"

Comment: If you're only interested in whether subset `('a', 'b', 'c')` from set 1 is in _any_ of the other tuples in set 2, just [break](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_break_statement.htm) out of your loop as soon as you find it. This stops you iterating over all tuples in set 2 for the subset `('a', 'b', 'c')`. Then move onto the next subset you're interested in.